# UI loads off centre whilst the Facebook login button works perfectly

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swift2

I am relatively new with user-interface design. So my question is when setting up my storyboard all of the UI is lined up as expected but when I run it on the iOS Simulator everything and all the UI is pushed over to the right whereas the Facebook button is laid out as expected. What am I doing wrong?

[image: iOS Simulator]
[image: UI]

Comment: My guess is you added the Facebook button programmatically and the rest in Interface Builder *without* some sort of auto layout

Comment: There's not nearly enough information to go on, but most likely the constraints in your storyboard are incorrect or missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you dealing with `Autolayout`? Sometimes if you don't use `Autolayout` your views will randomly appear to be placed correctly when run in the `Simulator`. This will make you think that there is something wrong when in fact this is expected behavior when not using `Autolayout`.

If you want your "Sign In", "Forget your password", and "Create Account" labels to be centered, follow these steps.

- Command click on those labels.
- Go to the bottom of the `Storyboard`
  pane and select the little button that looks like a smaller rectangle
  on top of a longer one.
- In that menu select "Horizontally in
  Container"
- click the "Add Constraints" button below.

You should also do this for the other view to get the to appear horizontally centered.

Comment: Ok so that solved half of it if you have a look above you will see what my UI looks like now

Comment: There's a button next to the one mentioned in my answer. It looks like a Star Wars Tie Fighter. Click on one of your views and then click that button at the bottom. At the top is a little menu-thingy that allows you to set the number of points you want the selected view to be from any of the other views. Play around with that until you get the spacing you need. THEN, there's a button next to the Tie Fighter button that looks like Darth Vader's Tie Fighter. Click on that and click "Update Frames" for all view or for just the view you've selected. It should do the trick.